# Gulp watch path excluding directory

Tags: javascript, gulp, coda

I have a Gulp watch task pointing at my SCSS files like so:

```
gulp.task('watch', () => {
  watch('assets/scss/**/*.scss', () => {
    gulp.start('css-development');
  });
});
```

My text editor Coda saves to a temporary buffer file such as `(A Document Being Saved By Coda)/styles.scss`. My watch task sees that file and tries to execute, so I need to get it to ignore any instance of that folder. What should my new watch path look like?

I image it would be something like this, although this is obviously wrong.

```
watch('assets/scss/**{!(A Document Being Saved By Coda)}/*.scss'
```

Comment: did the answer below work? If so mark as answered, if not, make a new answer about how you solved your problem!

Comment: @SquiresSquire No it didn't work. I never solved the problem so still waiting for a solution!

Comment: damn, I'm still hunting as well! I found the error only occurs when using Gulp on a network drive (Was a synology NAS, but the error has virtually gone since moving my dev server onto a Mac Mini, and SSHing into it

Answer (score 0):

If I understood that question right you want to ignore a specific file? If so this should work, just like in gulp.src:

```
gulp.watch('assets/scss/*.scss', ['!assets/scss/YourFile.scss']);
```

A quick response if it worked would be good, same if it not worked so we can figure out a better solution.